# Android Libgx Frogger game crashing: Could not find class 'com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGame'

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run the tutorial here: http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=175

Which is the Frogger game, I imported the projects and the Java version runs fine but when running the Android version I am getting a crash.   I'm pretty new to the whole thing, and am looking for some help.

Here is what I am getting:

```
12-20 17:32:01.725: E/dalvikvm(231): Could not find class 'com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGame', referenced from method com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGDX.onCreate
12-20 17:32:01.755: W/dalvikvm(231): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 611 (Lcom/rengelbert/froggergdx/FroggerGame;) in Lcom/rengelbert/froggergdx/FroggerGDX;
12-20 17:32:01.755: D/dalvikvm(231): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
12-20 17:32:01.755: D/dalvikvm(231): Making a copy of Lcom/rengelbert/froggergdx/FroggerGDX;.onCreate code (44 bytes)
12-20 17:32:01.875: D/dalvikvm(231): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.rengelbert.froggergdx/lib/libgdx.so 0x45f3d990
12-20 17:32:01.915: D/dalvikvm(231): Added shared lib /data/data/com.rengelbert.froggergdx/lib/libgdx.so 0x45f3d990
12-20 17:32:01.915: D/dalvikvm(231): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.rengelbert.froggergdx/lib/libgdx.so 0x45f3d990
12-20 17:32:01.949: D/AndroidRuntime(231): Shutting down VM
12-20 17:32:01.955: W/dalvikvm(231): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-20 17:32:01.955: E/AndroidRuntime(231): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGame
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGDX.onCreate(FroggerGDX.java:14)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-20 17:32:01.975: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 17:32:01.995: I/dalvikvm(231): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-20 17:32:01.995: E/dalvikvm(231): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
12-20 17:32:03.975: I/Process(231): Sending signal. PID: 231 SIG: 9
```

So I guess this is causing it: `12-20 17:32:01.725: E/dalvikvm(231): Could not find class 'com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGame', referenced from method com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGDX.onCreate`

I found this thread on the topic: [libgdx game not working in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346331/libgdx-game-not-working-in-android-phones)

And after going into Java Build Class and checking gdx.jar the backend jar file and FroggerDesktop file, I am still getting the crash.

If those files are dependencies why are they not automatically checked when I import the project?  I would think after importing the project everything should be set up to work?

Thanks for the help.